# how to use clause (where,and not ,or not) sql

Tags: mysql

How to use clause (where,and not,or not) if I have condition like this

- where table1.coloumn1='m'
- where table1.coloumn2 <>(not equal) table2.coloumn.2
- where table1.coloumn3<> (not equal)table2.coloumn3

I want to show 
 table1.coloumn1='m' and
( table1.colomn2-table2.coloumn2 and table1.coloumn3-table2.coloumn ) if they are not have values same.
Is use and, not , combine or,and?

Comment: Which ones do you want to "AND" and which ones "OR"?

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
select table1.*, table2.*
    from table1
    join table2 on table1.coloumn1='m' and table1.coloumn2<>table2.coloumn2 and table1.coloumn3 <> table2.coloumn3
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not write very clearly how you want to combine those conditions with the :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.column1='m' 
  AND  NOT table1.column2 != table2.column2 
   OR  NOT table1.column3 != table2.column3
```

Comment: Aren't the `NOT`s and `!=`s negating each other?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I was trying to help and give and example base on the limited information the question poster provided.